# Проверьте маленький регулярник

Tags: регулярные-выражения, delphi

В общем вот из такого куска кода:(php)

```
<td><img src='?p=captcha&cid=0j9lU2d8w137lc3NO0ZX4bX787tMuXbN'><br><input type=
```

нужно спарсить: 0j9lU2d8w137lc3NO0ZX4bX787tMuXbN

```
RegExp : TregExpr;
CaptchaSid : string;
begin
    RegExp := TRegExpr.Create;
    RegExp.Expression := '?p=captcha&cid=[d/]';
    RegExp.ModifierG := true;
    if RegExp.Exec  then
    begin
        ShowMessage(RegExp.Match[1]);
       end;
```

выдаёт ошибку в этой строке **if RegExp.Exec  then** а что не так я не знаю, помогите

Answer (score 1):

Вариант регулярного выражения - "/p=captcha&cid=(.*?)'><br>/i".
P.S. спец символы надо экранировать или вообще не использовать в выражении.